# selinux blocks ping from php exec

Tags: centos, permissions, selinux

Apache server running Centos7.  I'm trying to execute a ping from PHP's 'exec' command but get "socket: permission denied". It works with selinux disabled.   My linux knowledge is somewhat limited, I'm not sure how I can fix this.

Did some policy updates in selinux and ping now runs but gets 100% packet loss as if it couldn't reach the destination IP, but it reaches it with selinux disabled.

Comment: Please edit your post and show the output of `ausearch -ts recent -m avc -i` right after you've tried your pinging.

Answer (score 1):

I love when SELinux actually does catch the bad stuff. In this case,

1. `exec`: yeah, I can see how a server configuration would want to react allergically to a PHP script executing external executable; classic entry point. I at least hope you're actually not passing user input to some shell!
2. If you really need to do an ICMP request ("ping"), you'll need to give the calling executable (probably, /usr/bin/php or so) `ping_exec_t` file type. [Documentation](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/8-ping_selinux/).

All in all, if you are an inexperienced developer (we all are in some aspect!) it's very likely you're writing something that is *actually* exposing your server to remote execution problems (using `exec` in PHP is usually a really large red flag, that's why your CentOS configures SELinux to prohibit that). Calling `ping` can be replaced by you directly establishing (e.g., a TCP) connection to the service you're actually interested in, and you probably should do that, if possible.

Comment: No user input and the server has no internet access. This is done on a closed dev network.  It's for a simple front-end display to monitor about 30 other servers and will eventually be replaced with zabbix.  Currently, I use a cron job to run a bash script that pings all the servers then writes the output to a file. The page reloads the data from the file at a regular interval.  I thought it'd be a simple enough to cut out the first step entirely, I generally don't use exec but it seemed fitting for this case. I see no harm in executing ping here, especially with commands being hardcoded.

Comment: @Phaelaxz true, if hardcoded, this will very unlikely become problematic. Honestly, though, bash script to website sounds easier, if you want periodic checking and not "ping on HTTP request". What is it you really need?

Comment: Essentially the boss just wanted a simple "traffic light" monitor. Zabbix isn't set up yet and from what i've research doesn't really provide the clean traffic light display they want. Eventually i'll end up writing a plugin for a new widget and this dumb script can go the way of the dodo.

Comment: hm, sounds like grafana, but that's way more than a traffic light display; much effort to set up.

Comment: what does your boss actually want to monitor? Is it "*some* computer is reachable that replies to ICMP requests for a specific IP address", or is it "some specific *service* at a specific address is reachable" or "some specific *service* at a specific address is *functional*"?

Comment: Just that the different VMs are reachable, no specific service.

Comment: then ask the supervisor, not the VM itself. But: looking for reachability seems to me to be pretty useless in a virtualized environment; the likely failure mode is "service stopped working, but VM is still running", not "someone unplugged a virtual cable".

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Marcus Müller that you probably won't want this. But then, this'll probably work:

Create file `my-httpd-php-ping.te` and put this in it:

```
module my-httpd-php-ping 1.0;

require {
        type httpd_t;
        class capability { net_admin net_raw };
        class icmp_socket create;
        class rawip_socket { create getopt read setopt write };
}

#============= httpd_t ==============
allow httpd_t self:capability { net_admin net_raw };
allow httpd_t self:icmp_socket create;
allow httpd_t self:rawip_socket { create getopt read setopt write };
```

Compile it to a SELinux module like so:

```bsh
checkmodule -M -m -o my-httpd-php-ping.mod my-httpd-php-ping.te
semodule_package -o my-httpd-php-ping.pp -m my-httpd-php-ping.mod
```

And install it:

```bsh
semodule -i my-httpd-php-ping.pp
```

Afterwards, enable SELinux again:

```bsh
setenforce 1
```

Ping should now work. If not, post output of `ausearch -ts recent -m avc -i` like I asked in my comment.

Comment: Running ausearch I get <no matches>